# Why is the array printing in one file, but missing numbers when sent to another

Tags: c++, arrays, file, pointers

The main looks like this and it compiles fine, but when it calls to display the array that ptr is pointing to, something goes wrong

```
#include "tools.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    short int Arr1[] = { 5, 10 , 20 , 33, 444};
    short int Arr2[] = {8, 1, 22, 333, 4, 555, 6, 7777};
    short int* nptr ;
    short int* ar1 = Arr1;
    short int* ar2 = Arr2;
    Display(ar1);
    Display(ar2);
    nptr = Concat(ar1,ar2);
    Display(nptr);

}
```

This is the file that I am getting my functions from, display seems to work fine for the first two arrays and when printing the array while still in this file

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Display (short int* a)
{
    short int ArraySize = *a; 
    short int num = *a;
    for(short int i = 0; i < ArraySize; ++i)
      {
        num  = *(a+i);
        cout << num;
        cout << "  ";
      }
    cout << endl;
}




short int* Concat(short int* a1, short int* a2)
{       
    short int ArraySize = *a1 + *a2 + 1;
    cout << ArraySize << endl;
    short int Arr[ArraySize];
    short int num1 = *a1;
    short int num2 = *a2;   
    short int* ptr;
    ptr = &Arr[0];
    Arr[0] = ArraySize;
    for(short int i = 0; i < *a1; i++)
      {
        num1 = *(a1+i);
        Arr[i+1] = num1;
      }
    for (short int i = 0; i < *a2; i++)
      {      
        num2 = *(a2+i);
        Arr[i+*a1+1] = num2;
      }

    Display(ptr);
    return ptr;
}
```

Then the out put looks like this

```
5  10  20  33  444      // this line is fine
8  1  22  333  4  555  6  7777   // this line is fine
14 // fine
14  5  10  20  33  444  8  1  22  333  4  555  6  7777 // the way the array should be printed 
14  5  10  20  3448  64  0  0  4736  96  0  0  2096  64 // the way it is printing and I need to fix
```

If any one has any input on why this is doing this, or what I can do to fix it. I need the array to print from the main program, not from the file.

I would also like to mention that I am fairly new to pointers in this language.

Comment: Why not simply use `std::vector` and its functions such as `insert()` instead of things like `Concat`?  In addition `short int Arr[ArraySize];` is not valid C++, as arrays must be declared using compile-time constants not variables.  Plus `return ptr;` -- you're returning the address of a local variable -- undefined behavior.  There is just too much wrong with this (C) code.

Comment: [Actual C++ example of what you're trying to accomplish](http://ideone.com/gMp6a3)

Comment: I cannot use vector, I am to use pointers and iostream and that is all

Comment: Then you better list the things you can't use (not can use).  You're already using invalid C++ syntax to declare arrays.  Also, after you're finished with this class, throw it away and learn actual C++, as what you're writing is C code.

Comment: Do you know the lifetime of `short int Arr[ArraySize]`?  Do you know when it starts existing and when it stops existing?

Comment: Honestly, no, I am new to this and I am noy sure to where it should exist. I would think only in the function, but that doen't seem yo be right if the array will not print correctly from main

Comment: Watch out for `short int Arr[ArraySize];` This is what's known as a Variable Length Array. They are not supported by Standard C++ so can't be expected in all compilers. For example they are **not** supported by Visual Studio. They are a great way to overflow a stack with an unexpectedly large user-provided size and make a mess of `sizeof` at compile time. Be careful using them.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think you're unclear on a few things.

First off, you aren't dealing with any files here. These are arrays that are allocated on the stack. They are a specific size, and can't be changed.

Apologies if it seems like I'm talking down to you, that's not the intention, but it seems from what you're doing here that you don't understand the concept of the stack.

Your program uses the stack to keep track of where it is, as well as store local variables. When you call a function, it "pushes" the return address to the stack, as well as allocating space on the stack for local variables in that function. When you return from a function, it "pops" the stack and returns to the previous address. When that happens, local variables from the function are no longer valid.

In your code, you are declaring a local variable in Concat(). When you return from Concat(), the stack is popped, and the pointer that you return to that local variable is no longer valid.

To do what you're trying to do, you need to declare another array in main() that is big enough to hold what you need. You'll pass a pointer to that new array as a third parameter to Concat().

Don't let negativity get you down. No one was born an expert in this.

Comment: [Worth a discussion of the concept of Scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope). The answer pokes around the edges of scope, but instead seems to attribute scoping behaviour to the stack. This is a bit misleading, but as stacks implement local scope far more often than not the answer holds for any system OP is likely to see.

Comment: I have actually solved the problem, I was using an array to hold my values when, not a wrong way, but was not right for the way I wanted my program to run. I used the idea of ptr being a new int and it fixed the entirety of the problem

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, I was trying to explain the mechanics of why the program was printing the output it was rather than the theory behind it. It printed garbage after returning because that part of the stack was no longer valid. 

It's never a good idea to return a pointer to an object you allocated on the stack. With modern C++, most people don't deal with raw pointers anymore, anyhow.